# How to install ROS on pcDuino ? (Lubuntu 12.04 ARM)

Tags: ros, rosdep, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Last week, I've purchased a pcDuino. It comes with Lubuntu v12.04. In order to download, compile, and install ROS; I'm following the documentation of Pandaboard from this link the Pandaboard source installation

However, when I try to install the remaining dependencies with the

```
 sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
```

command.
It gives an error that says "Could Not Detect OS: tried windows,ubuntu,...." I don't know if it's because of the reason that pcDuino uses Lubuntu.
I've searched about this error but there is no certain answer that I've understood.

It would be appreciated if anybody can help me solve this problem or tell me just an easier way to install ROS on pcDuino?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67867/how-to-install-ros-on-pcduino-?-(lubuntu-12.04-arm)/) by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure Lubuntu is already supported (as in: rosdep knows about it), but just to get you going: you can use the environment variable `ROS_OS_OVERRIDE` to force rosdep to use the rules for a particular OS. Just make sure you set it to the right value for your OS. See [EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE) on the wiki for more information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-07-21**:
I will try that and get back to you. I suppose I should write ubuntu:12.04 correct?